# SAS countc function

Tags: sas

I am using SAS version 9.0.

For the function `countc(string,charlist, modifier)` I am using `AD` as a modifier, where `A` used for adding the alphabet and `D` used for adding digits.

While `D` is working fine but `A` is not working at all. I am applying on a code for checking the first 3 letter as alphabet or digit. Below is the code.

```
countc(scan(compress(code),1, "."), ,'AD')
```

**Example:**

```
code= V23.34 
Output = it just give blank.
Expected Output= 3

code= Vy.78
Output = blank
Expected output= 2

code= 568.789
Output = 3
expected output = 3
```

I am not sure whether `A` works with this version of SAS or not, because it is there in the documentation.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: You're likely not using SAS 9.0, more likely SAS 9.04? perhaps which is SAS 9.4

Comment: @Reeza Yes you are correct, the version was actually 9.04. I did not know it is same as 9.4

Comment: @Rushikumar Edited the question with expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your compress and scan logic worked  for me too and prx function will make it more general, below is the code which shows example for both

```
`
    data want;
    IF _N_ =1 THEN PATTERN = PRXPARSE ("/(^[A-Za-z0-9]{3})/");
    retain pattern;
     code= "V23.34" ;
     code= "V23134" ;
     if countc(scan(compress(code),1, "."), ,'AD') = 3 then flag= 'Y';
     else flag ='N';
     IF prxmatch(pattern, code) then flag1 ='Y'; else flag1 = 'N' ;
     run;
```

`

Comment: It worked when I am declaring "code"(input) in program itself.But does not work when I am using cards input method. It might not be taking it as a string though I have used double quotes. Anyway thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same value with a double quote on my SAS9.3 environment and I got 3 in the output.

Code 1, Without Cards:

```
data _null_;
code= "V23.34";
countc=countc(scan(compress(code),1, "."), ,'AD') ; 
put _all_;
run;
```

Code 2, With Cards:

```
data input;
input code $ 1-8;
cards;
V23.34
;
run;

data _null_;
set input;
countc=countc(scan(compress(code),1, "."), ,'AD') ; 
put _all_;
run;
```

Output:

```
code=V23.34 countc=3 _ERROR_=0 _N_=1
```

Comment: Is it maybe due to difference between SAS9.3 and SAS9.04 ?                      Also I have tried it using single quote and double quote, didnt work for me. One more thing I am taking the input through "cards" (from the program itself). It is making any difference ?

Comment: The code should work if declare your cards like this code below:

Comment: data _null_;
set input;
countc=countc(scan(compress(code),1, "."), ,'AD') ; 
put _all_;
run;